# prerender of static compiled js only get <html><head></head><body></body></html>

Tags: nginx, prerender

I have a static html page with a compiled gzjs file embeded. Used prerender, my nginx file is:

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    expires $expires;

    root /usr/local/www/nginx-dist;

    index index.html index.htm;

    #proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;

    location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
}

    location @prerender {
proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token MyToken;

set $prerender 0;
if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|googlebot-mobile|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
    set $prerender 1;
}
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
    set $prerender 1;
}
if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
    set $prerender 0;
}
if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
    set $prerender 0;
}

#resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
resolver 8.8.8.8;

if ($prerender = 1) {

    #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
    set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
    rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
    proxy_pass http://$prerender;
}

if ($prerender = 0) {
        rewrite .* /index.html break;
    }
  }
}
```

get only 301 and

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

by googlebot fetch.

According to prerender.io, "You need to switch to a server (like Unicorn or Puma) that lets you start multiple processes or use non-blocking I/O so that there isn't a deadlock when Prerender tries to render your page on the fly", 
can anyone advise how to do it for my situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same issue, but couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: yes, solved, with help from support@prerender.io , my final nginx file is below

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the nginx config, then you don't need to switch to Unicorn/Puma since those are Rails servers.

Can you send the URL you are testing when you see this issue to our support team? We'll be able to help you look into this and make sure everything is working properly. Just send an email to support@prerender.io and we'll be happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

with help from official support, my final nginx file is:

```
 server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name www.YOURSITE.com;
expires $expires;

root /usr/local/www/nginx-dist;

index index.html index.htm;

proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;

location / {
    if ($uri ~* "\.(php|jsp)") {
        return 404;
    }

    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOURTOKEN;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|Googlebot-Image|googlebot-mobile|Google-Structured-Data-Testing-Tool|AdsBot-Google-Mobile|Mediapartners-Google|bingbot|MSNBot|msnbot-media|AdsBot-Google-Mobile|yandex|baiduspider|Baiduspider-mobile|Baiduspider-image|Baiduspider-video|Baiduspider-news|Baiduspider-favo|Baiduspider-cpro|twitterbot|facebot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|tumblr|xml-sitemaps|vkShare|W3C_Validator|redditbot|Slack-ImgProxy|Slackbot-LinkExpanding|Site
    Analyzer|SiteAnalyzerBot|Viber|Whatsapp|Telegram|Slurp|Slurp China|Discordbot|Sogou web spider|Sogou Pic Spider|Sogou Push Spider|YoudaoBot|YoudaoFeedFetcher|Sosospider|Sosoimagespider|360Spider|Speedy Spider|HuaweiSymantecSpider|iaskspider") {
    set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
     }
    #if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
    #    set $prerender 0;
    # }

    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

   #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
   resolver 8.8.8.8;

   if ($prerender = 1) {
        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /https://$server_name$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

}